# Этапы работы компилятора

Tags: парсер, компиляция, семантика, трансляция, лексер

Читаем википедию:

Процесс компиляции, как правило, состоит из нескольких этапов:

- лексический анализ;
- синтаксический анализ;
- семантический анализ;
- ...

Вроде и перечисленные виды анализов описаны в википедии, да и на других сайтах. Но везде по-разному и чётко разграничить эти понятия не получается.

Самое важно что интересует: что поступает на вход и в каком виде выходит после каждого анализа?

Comment: А там в википедии прямо это и сказано. вот прямо в тех самых предложениях. Лексический анализ создает из потока символов поток лексем, вот этот поток лексем он и отдает синтаксическому. А тот генерит дерево разбора, которое и передает дальше в семантику

Comment: А разграничить их да, совсем и полностью нельзя. у некоторых компиляторов например лексер советуется с синтаксиром, потому что в некоторых языках однозначно определить лексемы невозможно без понимания контекста, доступного только на этапе синтаксического анализа

Comment: Немного не так описано, но допустим. Лексема и токен это одно и тоже? Что из себя представляет дерево разбора после синтаксического анализатора?

Comment: Да, практически одно и то же. думаю можно какие то нюансы найти, но это скорее будет игра слов и разные люди могут немного по разному для себя это определять. Дерево ... ну оно зависит от автора компилятора, как ему удобнее. например что то в этом роде https://pastebin.com/2EcT88yR

Comment: чувствую, нужно @sitev_ru прочитать книгу дракона.

Comment: Что за книга дракона?

Comment: вот, например, ссылка http://literature-edu.ru/informatika/12711/index.html?page=2 и там синтаксическое дерево http://literature-edu.ru/pars_docs/refs/13/12711/12711_html_m25172573.png, я думал, что так должно выглядеть дерево после семантического анализатора

Comment: @sitev_ru я вам привел в общем то точно такое же дерево, только рисовать в тексте мне было влом. и не вижу необходимости держать в дереве всякие begin/end. но это уже дело вкуса. А книга дракона ... в викапедии о компиляторах в низу "См. также" не смотрели ? там ссылка есть https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B:_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%8B,_%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку! Немного не понял, чем отличается синтаксическое дерево от дерева после семантического анализатора?

Comment: ну самое простое что я вижу, это на дерево с предыдущего этапа навешиваются дополнительные атрибуты узлам. может ссылки на объявления переменных или еще что. что бы было ясно, что переменная "X" в одной части дерева и в другой части это одна и та же переменная) (на примере изобразил в виде ID) https://pastebin.com/2RDiYpNC

Comment: Оказывается не там смотрел в википедии. Вот тут https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80 пункт "Структура компилятора" понятно написано)), хотя уже и так разобрался. Всем спасибо!